# How do I design a mobile table with multiple headers?

Tags: website-design, tables, mobile-web, css

I have the following table design for PC.
How can I make it easier to see that "ddd", "eee", and "fff" are groups of "CCC" in mobile view?

【PC】

[image]

【MOBILE】

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the origin, not the destination.

The hierarchy ranks in the original table are given by position, typographic style and color, except in the second hierarchy, which maintains the same color as the first.

By modifying just this, you already have much of the problem solved. In this extremely simple example, there's an indentation to accentuate it:

[image: first]

Hierarchies in a landscape table are more evident because the eye follows the reading order:

- left → right
- top → bottom

In a vertical table one of these readings is eliminated so hierarchies must be emphasized by other means. The **visual contrasts** is the design tool for those cases.
With very simple design tricks you can get better results:

[image: Second]

Comment: Small nitpick, but you should probably switch `up > down` with `top > bottom` as you don't read up to down, you read top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks (spanglish  ). Next time you can edit the answer to fix it.